# Rails - delete one side of a one-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, one-to-many, relationship

Quick question:

If I have a one-to-many relationship, such as this:

```
class SalesPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deals
end

class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sales_person
end
```

how can I delete a Sales Person, without negatively impacting the deals associated with them?  The use-case for this would be if someone left the organization.  We still need a record of the deals in the database, but that sales person record is no longer needed.

Would it just be better to have an active/inactive flag on the sales person instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of situations I've use [acts_as_paranoid](http://acts_as_paranoid), basically It adds a new timestamps column: `deleted_at` and overrides some of your AR finders.

Comment: +1 for soft deletes - at a previous organization we used them exclusively and they saved our butts more than once.